# How to connect between python code and c code

Tags: python, c

I would like to know how can i connect between python file and c file.
I need to connect with them , so i can use functions from both files.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Search Google before asking on SO. It's common courtesy to waste your own time before that of others.

Answer (score 1):

Basic stuff that changes across C and Python is data types. I used `ctypes` python module to achieve conversion. Once data types are converted/formatted properly for C, you may pass these as arguments to C functions. C apis can remain as it is and changes are required in py code.

Consider looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

I have an example code here: https://github.com/Vishwajith-K/snippets/tree/py-c/bitwisepy